# Pandas groupby check if a column is strictly increasing wrt another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe, df:

```
Subject Marks1 Marks2
English  1      10
English  1.5    20
English  1.7    30
English  3      40
Science  1      10
Science  1.5    20
Science  1.7    15
Science  3      35
```

I want to group by subjects and check if Marks2 is strictly increasing with increasing Marks1. If not then I want to remove that group from df and put it in another issues dataframe. So finally I will have,
df:

```
Subject Marks1 Marks2
English  1      10
English  1.5    20
English  1.7    30
English  3      40
```

issues:

```
Subject Marks1 Marks2
Science  1      10
Science  1.5    20
Science  1.7    15
Science  3      35
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with compare for less values like `0` with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for all columns, then get `vals` for subject and filter output by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
m = df.groupby('Subject').diff().le(0).any(axis=1)

vals = df.loc[m, 'Subject']
mask = df['Subject'].isin(vals)
df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)
   Subject  Marks1  Marks2
4  Science     1.0      10
5  Science     1.5      20
6  Science     1.7      15
7  Science     3.0      35

df2 = df[~mask]
print (df2)
   Subject  Marks1  Marks2
0  English     1.0      10
1  English     1.5      20
2  English     1.7      30
3  English     3.0      40
```

EDIT: Bottleneck is in difference per groups, if all groups are sorted is possible improve performance by:

```
#columns used for difference (passed to groupby())
cols = ['Subject','col1','col2']
#sorting by all columns (if possible and if necessary)
df = df.sort_values(cols)
m = df[['Marks1','Marks2']].diff().le(0).any(axis=1) & df.duplicated(cols)

vals = df.loc[m, 'Subject']
mask = df['Subject'].isin(vals)
df1 = df[mask]
```

Comment: this works but is quite slow, as in the real data I have to groupby 5 columns and compare if 7th column is increasing with increase in 6th, and there are 8M such groups.

Comment: @Ank - So problem is in `df.groupby(['Subject', 'col2'..'col5']).diff()` - slow ?

Comment: @Ank - answer was eidted, working, if all groups are separately like `group1, groups2,...group_last`, then is possible use `diff` only per both columns and chain duplicated.

Comment: yes, the edited version is much faster as my dataframe is pretty much already sorted

Comment: OK, sorting is key here, super, glad can help ;)

Comment: in the edited version, shouldn't you also sort by Marks1 column?

Answer (score 0):

`.filter()` using a `lambda` function that finds the `.diff()` to identify issues

```
 issues=df.groupby('Subject').filter(lambda x : ((x.Marks1.diff()>0)&(x.Marks2.diff()<0)).any())
    print(issues)


 Subject  Marks1  Marks2
4  Science     1.0      10
5  Science     1.5      20
6  Science     1.7      15
7  Science     3.0      35


Noissues=df[~df.index.isin(issues.index)]
print(Noissues)



  Subject  Marks1  Marks2
0  English     1.0      10
1  English     1.5      20
2  English     1.7      30
3  English     3.0      40
```